Download Excel File over HTTPS in ABAP
I am using CL_HTTP_CLIENT and trying to download a Excel file from HTTPS URL in ABAP
Basically, the URL points to Excel export / download functionality of a reporting web application
When I directly input the URL in browser, it simply starts the Excel download in background (can be seen by clicking the Downloads)
I can't reveal the actual URL as it is intranet but it is similar to the below URL
https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/data/files/EE/E3/A1/59/6266F610BB8E41E6894D49A8/LFT_2019.xls
The above link directly points to an existing static Excel file but the URL I am talking about executes the action "generate the report and export it as Excel sheet" which then behaves like the above link. It also allows filtering criteria for generating the report as parameters in URL
It looks like
https://example.com/sap/crp/cdo?type=CRP_L&list=36&$ge$contract_signed_date=20240401&$product_group_id=XYZ&chart_display=true&chart_type=line&csv=X
contract_signed_date and product_group_id are filter parameters and last parameter csv=X is an instruction to the server to export the report as Excel spreadsheet output
While the Excel file download in the background, the browser shows blank html body as response
Right now I am able to get only this blank html body as response using CL_HTTP_CLIENT client with lo_http_client->response->get_data( )
How to capture the Excel file that silently gets downloaded in the background?
Hope, I am able to explain well... please let me know

Just to add, I am getting http code 200 as status response lo_http_client->response->get_status( ) and I am able to get actual application errors from the server, which tells me that I am able to successfully reach out to the reporting application over http. The blank html body in response is expected.

It can be many things, you should add the details to your question. I suggest that you get the whole response, especially the header fields. You might find some redirection for instance (they are not followed automatically by CL_HTTP_CLIENT).

Thank you Sandra for the response and the pointer to any other headers that may be returned. Actually, some sort of progress bar runs when the URL is accessed in browser, so the Excel output may not be technically the response of the URL and it may be asynchronous response, meaning the URL request returns with a response and a separate process then connects back to browser to output the Excel as download. Any idea how to positively verify that is the case?

It's not an ABAP question for now. You must analyze the HTTP responses after you send your HTTP request (Developer tools, Fiddler). Check the other questions in Stack Overflow. It's not a reproducible problem, people can't tell you what is wrong.

I agree and no worries. Thanks for the pointers. I thought, this is a straight easy and directly jumped to ABAP where this file is needed but looks like a bit of orchestration is involved in producing that Excel output in browser. I will analyze at a later time as literally I am pressed to provide an alternative - may be a Python script at command line and SM69. Oh wonderful!

Maybe you forgot to call http client receive method. Below example is working.
REPORT zmky_http_download.

DATA: lo_client   TYPE REF TO if_http_client,
      lv_url      TYPE string,
      lv_response TYPE xstring.

* Set the URL of the endpoint
lv_url = 'https://www.tesourodireto.com.br/data/files/EE/E3/A1/59/6266F610BB8E41E6894D49A8/LFT_2019.xls'.

* Create HTTP client
cl_http_client=>create_by_url( EXPORTING url = lv_url  IMPORTING client = lo_client  ).
IF lo_client IS BOUND.

  TRY.
*     Set request parameters
      lo_client->request->set_method( 'GET' ).

*      * Send the request
      lo_client->send( ).

*      * Get the response
      lo_client->receive( ).
      lv_response = lo_client->response->get_data( ).

      WRITE: / 'Response:', lv_response.

    CATCH cx_root INTO DATA(lx_root).
      WRITE: / 'Error:', lx_root->get_text( ).
  ENDTRY.

ENDIF.


thank you for responding, I am literally the above call sequence except for the fact that in my case, I am using a RFC destination with SSL Certificate to access the site as it does certificate logon. By the way, your code gives error at receive method - SSL handshake with www.tesourodireto.com.br:443 failed: SSSLERR_PEER_CERT_UNTRUSTED (-102)
Peer's X.509 certificate (chain) validation failed (missing trust?). However, this is least of my worries as in my case the Certificate based SSL shakehand goes fine and I get 200 response code, but I don't get the Excel file as response payload

You need to install the server certificate (www.tesourodireto.com) via STRUST. There isn't a login certificate for this endpoint.  I got the Excel file with the above code.
